# How does the router know how to route the packets to my terminal?

Tags: routing, nat

Suppose I have a network of 2 computers, each having a private network address of 192.168.1.101 and 192.106.1.102.

For my public ip address, it is 10.2.10.172.

When I make a http request to google.com, my computer will send out a packet with source ip address of 192.168.1.101 to the router and the NAT will change it to 10.2.10.172.

My question is, when google.com gets the request, and sends the reply back to 10.2.10.172, how does the router knows which computer to route to? (192.168.1.101 or 192.168.1.102).

I was thinking about port number at first but I think that we could be browsing on the same website at the same time so I have no idea how it works here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UDP hole punching NAT port](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10207/udp-hole-punching-nat-port)

Comment: The 10 network is also "internal non-routable" -- I'm working fast through the queue tonight, so maybe I'm bonkers... there's another layer of NAT must be happening to turn that 10 net number into a publick routable. Anyway... McKevin, welcome to Net Eng! This is a softball Q for here, but it's on topic enough I suppose...

Comment: @CraigConstantine I'm just a CCNA student, I guess that explains on the softball Q :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**NAT**
If you are using static (one-to-one) [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Basic_NAT), the router will assign the `11.2.10.172` public IP to the first PC ( for example `192.168.1.101` ) trying to reach google.com. In this case, the two PC will not be able to communicate with google.com at once, because the only available public IP is already distributed.
The NAT table in the router:
`11.2.10.172 -> 192.168.1.101`

**PAT**
In your case [PAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Port_address_translation) ( NAT overloading ) is the solution.
With PAT, multiple addresses can be mapped to one private IP. When a device initiates a TCP/IP session, it generates a TCP or UDP source port number to uniquely identify the session. When the router receives this packet it uses that source port number to uniquely identify the translation.

**Example**
PC1 (`192.168.1.101`) makes an HTTP request to google.com (`64.233.161.1`) with a random source port number (1444). PC1 will send a packet with `DA: 64.233.161.1:80 | SA: 192.168.1.101:1444`. When the router receives this packet it inserts `11.2.10.172:1444 -> 192.168.1.101:1444` to the NAT table then changes the L3 addressing of the packet to `DA: 64.233.161.1:80 | SA: 11.2.10.172:1444` and forwards it to google.com.
Google responds with `DA: 11.2.10.172:1444 | SA: 64.233.161.1:80`. The router receives this packet and translates it to `DA: 192.168.1.101:1444 | SA: 64.233.161.1:80` then forwards it to PC1.

If PC2 (`192.168.1.102`) sends a packet with the same source port number as PC1 did , the router simply increases the port number by 1. In that case the NAT table would look like this

`11.2.10.172:1444 -> 192.168.1.101:1444`
`11.2.10.172:1445 -> 192.168.1.102:1444`

I hope it helps a bit.

**UPDATE**
As @CraigConstantine noticed, `10.2.10.172` is still in the [private address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) so I have changed it to `11.2.10.172`.

Comment: so you mean we will be having 2 port numbers in the packet? one for the NAT and one for the terminal (http port 80)?

Comment: Yes. The PC sends a packet with  <dest: 64.233.161.1:80, source 192.168.1.101>. The router translates it to <dest: 64.233.161.1:80, source: 10.2.10.172:1317> and sends it to Google. Google responds with <dest: 10.2.10.172:1317, source: 64.233.161.1:80>. The router receives the packet, searches for the 10.2.10.172:1317 mapping in the NAT table. Finds the correct row, translates, and sends the packet to the PC with <dest: 192.168.1.101, source: 64.233.161.1:80>

Comment: Only one in the packet.  the router re-writes the destination address and port numbers as it translates.

Comment: If we want to get all technical (and who wouldn't?) the PC does assign a source port which is then translated by the NAT device. So in Adam's comment the first source would really be more like 192.168.1.101:33123, and likewise the corresponding final destination at the end of his comment would be 192.168.1.101:33123.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You are right. I forgot that. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Ron I don't really understand your comment. AFAIK the source port and destination port are both in the packet.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood @McKevin's comment.  I took it as he was assuming additional information was in the packet.

Comment: @Ron was right, I meant 2 sets of port number, now that it's clear to me, I will mark as accepted answer. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6):

Your router knows where to route traffic because it maintains a table of [stateful connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) which are source IPaddress:port and destination IPaddress:port relationships. These are established based on your firewall rules, NAT policies, and a few other settings (like TCP and UDP timeout). There are 4 possible states: NEW, RELATED, ESTABLISHED and INVALID. Based on your firewall rules, your firewall determines what state a connection should be in. So typically, you can make NEW connections outbound by default, but only RELATED or ESTABLISHED connections are allowed inbound if you create a NAT or PAT rule and matching firewall policy to allow this.

Then, either based on the rules you have configured (for the case of a NEW connection) or the existing connection table (for the case of an ESTABLISHED connection) a packet will be allowed or disallowed through.

Furthermore, an [ARP] table is maintained which helps to firewall to know what physical [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) an IP address corresponds to.