# Static NAT and PAT

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, nat, network-access, access-control

I have two private IP addresses, want to make them NAT to 203.0.113.0/2 public IP address.

WAY 1 : Static NAT (2 ip addresses NATted to one by manually)

WAY 2 : PAT (Router gives port number for each device randomly)

Question is that : Why doesn't router apply the same things on Static NATting?

Comment: "_want to make them NAT to 10.10.10.1 public IP address._" Actually `10.10.10.1` is not a public IP address, it is in the `10.0.0.0/8` Private IPv4 address block.

Comment: Hello mr Ron Maupin. I ' ve just put example to understand the main background of the procedure.

Comment: Then you should use an address from one of the three address blocks IANA has set aside for that: `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`. That way people know you are giving an example, not that you are completely confused about public/private addressing.

Comment: I want to understand that why router doesnt give different port number on static routing if it must be applied.

Comment: You have tagged [tag:cisco-asa], which is a firewall, not a router. Do You mean an ASA, or do you have some router? We also need to see a lot more detail. Please give us the exact configurations. A full (sanitized) configuration is the best, but we really need to see the commands you are using to create and apply the NAT.

Comment: Firstly i have changed my public address on my post.Actually i used this tag to make my question post publishable. I don't have real problem on practice.I want to mean still one question. That is about NAT technology use different ways on translating. Why PAT gives randomly port number to the private devices but Static NAT doesn't give.

Comment: Basic NAT only translates the network addresses, while NAPT (what Cisco calls PAT) also translates the transport protocols address (port) for TCP and UDP, and the Query ID for ICMP. _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663)_ and _[RFC 3022, Traditional IP Network Address Translator (Traditional NAT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3022)_ go into more detail, but it would help if we had a specific router model because different routers do it differently.

Comment: Some of that is explained in [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53937/8499), including the problems with NAPT, along with a lot more information about the IPv4 address shortage.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The router (or ASA) giving different ports for a [Dynamic PAT](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/dynamic-pat/) *is* what allow multiple hosts to share a single public IP address *at the same time*.

[This answer will explain why a Dynamic PAT must change the Port number](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47517/why-does-nat-translate-a-source-port/47522#47522).

Either way, the ASA will allow you to configure two [Static NAT](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/static-nat/)'s, but keep in mind the translation will only apply in the outbound direction. On the inbound direction, only one Static NAT will apply.

Meaning if you have two Internal hosts:  10.0.0.11 and 10.0.0.22, and you configure two Static NATs:

```
object network HOST1
  host 10.0.0.11
  nat (inside,outside) static 72.9.9.33

object network HOST2
  host 10.0.0.22
  nat (inside,outside) static 72.9.9.33
```

When either host makes a outbound request, their traffic will be translated to 72.9.9.33.  BUT, if anyone external initiates a request to 72.9.9.33, *it will only be translated to Host1's IP address*.

So it isn't a true Static NAT. It's a true Static NAT for the first host (inbound and outbound), and a psuedo Static NAT for the second host (outbound only).

If you only need specific ports to access the internal servers, you're better off configuring a [Static PAT](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/static-pat/).

Answer (score 0):

PAT is used to translate multiple private IP addresses to a single public IP address.
PAT is used for internet connectivity mostly..

Static NAT is used to translate a single private IP address with a single public IP address. When application is hosted in the internal network wants to access application from internet static NATting is used. It's one to one NATting ...

PAT is many to one natting pat is also called NAT overload..

Comment: Port adress translation is for outbound traffic Static nat is for inbound traffic..